# pylint doesn't seem to work with dicts defined in dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-dataclasses

It seems that pylint is not able to recognize a dictionary defined in a dataclass.

Consider the following code:

```py
# pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods, missing-docstring

from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Foo:
    collection: dict = field(default_factory=dict)

F = Foo()
F.collection[1] = 2
```

Under pylint, this gives the following error.

```
************* Module temp    
temp.py:10:0: E1137: 'F.collection' does not support item assignment (unsupported-assignment-operation)
```

I tried using `typing.Dict[int, int]` as type annotation and it still gives the same error.

Any suggestions on how to make pylint recognize the type of collection in above case?

Comment: There are a couple of github issues open about this: [example](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2698).  All of the solutions I can think of for this would be basically turning your dataclass into a regular class.